# Adobe CQ5.6.1 Authenticaltion for Publish instance

Tags: aem

I am settig up a local Adobe CQ 5.6.1 author and publish instances for development. I want to password protect the publish instance, since the customer demands that. As of now, I do not have SSO or any other authentication mechanism. Is it possible to have authentication for the publish instance just the way it is avalable for the author instance? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, it is called Closed User Group. You can find the documentation here:
http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/howto/create_apply_cug.html

Another option is to have a proxy in front of your CQ instance which protects the page.